# Can I prevent Windows 7 from redrawing the primary monitor when second monitor is unplugged?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a Windows 7 laptop with a second monitor plugged in via DisplayPort.  Both the laptop screen and the secondary monitor have the same resolution.

When I'm "going mobile", I'll move all of my windows to the primary screen of the laptop, then unplug my secondary monitor.  Every time I do this Windows will redraw the windows on the primary monitor so that ones that were maximized no longer are, sometimes they're resized all funny, and I have to go back through and set things how I want them on the laptop screen.  I'll typically have an application maximized to a single monitor and this is the effect that seems to break most.

Why does this do this, and is there any way to prevent it? I think I would like the primary laptop screen to stay as-is when the secondary monitor is unplugged.

Comment: Does this still happen if you do **not** move around the windows before disconnecting the secondary monitor?

Comment: It might have been a little better...Chrome looked like it un-maximized (was originally on the primary monitor), and it did move the IDE that was on the secondary monitor over and I think it may have kept *that* maximized.  I'll play with it some more - I thought in the past I'd had problems with windows being stuck on the now-unplugged monitor and had trouble moving them back. But maybe not rearranging them will have less headache than the other way.

Comment: as long as the system (windows) knows the monitor was pulled it does rearrange most windows, although some programs can remain offscreen  improperly, or when re-opened. Win-P and select computer only to "inform the system" before just pulling plugs out.  The problem with the windows size , is your resolution it is different between the 2 monitors?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Nope, both screens are the same resolution.